# Center a button created in React with CSS

Tags: html, css

This is the React component:

```
var CreatePerson = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <Row id='test'>
                <Col md={1}>
                    <Button bsStyle="primary" type="button" bsSize="small">Merge</Button>
                </Col>
                <Col md={1}>
                    <Button bsStyle="Secondary" type="button" bsSize="small">Delete</Button>
                </Col>
                <Col md={2}>
                    {this.props.dirty_record}
                </Col>
                <Col md={2}>
                    {this.props.user.email}
                </Col>
                <Col md={1}>
                    {this.props.user.first}
                </Col>
                <Col md={1}>
                    {this.props.user.last}
                </Col>
                <Col md={1}>
                    {this.props.user.title}
                </Col>              
                <Col md={1}>
                    {this.props.user.company}
                </Col>
            </Row>
        )
    }
});
```

This is my CSS file

```
#test {padding-top: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      }
```

When the page loads, the `<Col>` that have `{this.props...}` are centered but not the buttons. The buttons are aligned at the bottom edge.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Im not very familiar with react but if I understood you right you want the button to be at the center of the screen? Because that CSS will only make the text inside it centered within the button, it won't do anything to the button itself except add a little padding to the top.

Comment: Ahh ok. Is there a way to center the button itself?

Comment: I don't know what your files look like, but you can e.g. use something like #button {margin: auto 0}, but that doesn't always work. You can also use fixed/absolute positioning, so e.g. #button{position:absolute;width:6cm;left:calc(50%-3cm);}

Comment: Yes there is. Just google `CSS center elements` there's HEAPS of info out there on centering stuff in CSS.

Comment: #test Button {position:absolute;left:50%} should change the position of your button. The code before with #button needs you to add id="button" to your buttons for it to work.

Comment: thank you! I didn't know what to google :-)